# Updating tiles on canvas in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, gis

I have a program which is basicly a simple GIS (mapping software), and i'we found out how to make The tiles and all that, but i dont know how to move the tiles around The screen (which is pretty important unless you just want to see the initial zoom-level ;)

So basically, I want to, on the run be able to:

1) draw new pictures on the canvas on-the run. Which is proberly realated to:

2) move images (to new coordinates)

And

3) delete pictures (when they get out of the screen. This is less important, and I think I can find the solution to this myself, but I can't find the answer to number 2

Hope you can help me (and others using tkinter)

Comment: What have you tried so far? The way to manipulate objects in a canvas is to store the object `id` returned from the `canvas.create_...` function, and to apply changes via `canvas.itemconfig(id_, ...`.

Comment: I'll try that tomorow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What part about moving and deleting items on the canvas don't you understand?

There are two methods that let you move objects on a canvas:

- [coords](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.coords-method) lets you query or modify all of the coordinates that make up a canvas object or group of objects.
- [move](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.move-method) lets you move an object or group of objects by a relative offset in the x and y direction

To delete an object or group of objects you can use the [delete](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.delete-method) method.

In all cases you can give an id for a single object, or a tag that matches multiple objects on the canvas.

- The id is the value that is returned by the method used to create an object.
- A tag is something you can attach to one or more objects on a canvas. For example, you could give the tag "tile" to all the tiles, and delete all the tiles with a single command, while keeping all other objects such as legends, annotations, UI elements, etc.

Comment: ok... thats embarising... i used like 4 hours searching for a way to do it, and the command was named move... but thank you!!!